# How can I tell if Rails code is being run via rake or script/generate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a plugin that is a bit heavy-weight. (Bullet, configured with Growl notifications.) I'd like to not enable it if I'm just running a rake task or a generator, since it's not useful in those situations. Is there any way to tell if that's the case?

Comment: See this answer to further distinguish between `rake`, `rails c`, `rails s`, `rails g`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53963584/293280

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's as simple as that:

```
if $rails_rake_task
  puts 'Guess what, I`m running from Rake'
else
  puts 'No; this is not a Rake task'
end
```

#### Rails 4+

Instead of `$rails_rake_task`, use:

```
File.basename($0) == 'rake'
```

Comment: This works, but it's ugly, because it depends on Rake internally defining a global variable - which might go away in the future

Comment: In Rails 4, the above didn't work for me, but **if File.basename($0) == 'rake'** still did.

Comment: This doesn't work now that running rake tasks via `rails` is SOP.

Comment: It's actually preferred to use `$PROGRAM_NAME` instead of `$0` to be more explicit.

Answer (score 9):

I like NickMervin's answer better, because it does not depend on the internal implementation of Rake (e.g. on Rake's global variable).

This is even better - no regexp needed

```
  File.split($0).last == 'rake'
```

File.split() is needed, because somebody could start `rake` with it's full path, e.g.:

```
  /usr/local/bin/rake taskname
```

Comment: Given some recent experiences trying to determine if the environment is running within rake, testing $0 is the most reliable. defined?(::Rake) seemed to always be true, at least in Rails, so that did not work. I looked for global variables but did not find anything suitable.

Answer (score 7):

`$0` holds the current ruby program being run, so this should work:

```
$0 =~ /rake$/
```

Answer (score 4):

The most stable option is to add `$is_rake = true` at the beginning of `Rakefile` and use it from your code.

Use of `$0` or `$PROGRAM_NAME` sometimes will fail, for example when using spring and checking variables from config/initializers

Answer (score 3):

It appears that running `rake` will define a [global variable `$rakefile`](http://rubyforge.org/frs/shownotes.php?release_id=1076), but in my case it gets set to `nil`; so you're better off just checking if `$rakefile` has been defined... seeing as `__FILE__` and `$FILENAME` don't get defined to anything special.

```
$ cat test.rb 
puts(global_variables.include? "$rakefile")
puts __FILE__
puts $FILENAME
$ cat Rakefile 
task :default do
    load 'test.rb'
end
$ ruby test.rb
false
test.rb
-
$ rake
(in /tmp)
true
./test.rb
-
```

Not sure about script/generator, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the plugin using environment variable:

```
$ DISABLE_BULLET= 1 rake some:task
```

And then in your code:

```
unless ENV['DISABLE_BULLET']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

We could ask this

```
Rake.application.top_level_tasks
```

In a rails application, this is an empty array, whereas in a Rake task, the array has the task name in it.

`top_level_tasks` probably isn't a public API, so it's subject to changes. But this is the only thing I have found.