# How to determine if Rails is running from CLI, console or as server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, rack-middleware

I have a [middleware for announcing my application on the local network app using Bonjour](https://github.com/crishoj/rack_jour), but it's also announcing the service when Rails is invoked from rake or through the console.

I'd like to exclude these cases, and only use the Bonjour middleware when Rails is running as a server.

The middleware configuration accepts a proc to exclude middlewares under certain conditions using a `proc`:

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::SSL, :exclude => proc { |env| 
  env['HTTPS'] != 'on' 
}
```

But how do I determine if Rails was invoked from the CLI, console or as a server?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Peeking at the `Rails` module using [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) reveals that console invocations can be detected like this:

```
Rails.const_defined? 'Console'
```

And server invocations like this:

```
Rails.const_defined? 'Server'
```

Comment: Interestingly, this only works if the commands "rails s" or "rails c" are invoked. If you're running a server via a different command (e.g., "unicorn_rails"), these constants never get defined. Rails::Server looks like it's defined as part of the command-parsing process, even though it inherits from ::Rack::Server.

Comment: This is not working for me with Rails 4 even with rails c. I am getting Server and Console defined in the console.

Comment: @MarkTabler @DanHerman try this if starting Rails with unicorn? `(Rails.const_defined? 'Server') || ($0.include? 'unicorn')`

Comment: `Rails::Server` is still defined in generator scripts like `rails g migration`.

Comment: `Server` is not definded when use passenger

Comment: Also doesn't work when used in an initializer.

Answer (score 20):

### Summary of the environment for each command.

I found the existing answers to be either incomplete, redundant or not exhaustive. So here is a table format of each command and what the resulting environment looks like.

#### Rails 7.0

```
| Command                            |  Rails.const_defined?( "Console" )  |  Rails.const_defined?( "Server" ) |               ARGV              | Rake.application.top_level_tasks |
|------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|---------------------------------|----------------------------------|
| `rake db:migrate:status`           |  false                              |  false                            |  ["db:migrate:status"]          | ["db:migrate:status"] 
| `rails console`                    |  true                               |  false                            |  []                             | []
| `rails server`                     |  false                              |  true                             |  []                             | []
| `rails g migration new_migration`  |  false                              |  false                            |  ["migration", "new_migration"] | []
| `rails r "puts 'Hi'"`              |  false                              |  false                            |  ["puts 'hi'"]                  | []
```

#### Rails 4.2

```
| Command                            |  Rails.const_defined?( "Console" )  |  Rails.const_defined?( "Server" )  |               ARGV              |
|------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|------------------------------------|---------------------------------|
| `rake db:migrate:status`           |  false                              |  true                              |  ["db:migrate:status"]          |
| `rails console`                    |  true                               |  true                              |  []                             |
| `rails server`                     |  false                              |  true                              |  []                             |
| `rails g migration new_migration`  |  false                              |  true                              |  ["migration", "new_migration"] |
| `rails r "puts 'Hi'"`              |  false                              |  true                              |  []                             |
```

You can see that just checking for "Server" being defined as a `Rails` constant will not catch generators, like `rails g migration`. You need to check the `ARGV` to do that.

I hope this helps. I only had immediate access to Rails 4.2 but feel free to add sections for other Rails versions, as well as add any additional commands that need "catching".

NOTE: I found in Rails 7 (and maybe in some other version between 4.2 and 7) this changed quite dramatically and a few of our checks were failing because of it, so I updated the answer for Rails 7.0 and had to include a new command `Rake.application.top_level_tasks` to make things work on our end again. Hope it helps.

Comment: In Rails 5.2 `Rails.const_defined?( "Server" )` is `true` only when running `rails server`. 

When the server is started not with the Rails command, an additional check for the program name will help:

`Rails.const_defined?(:Server) || $PROGRAM_NAME.include?('puma')`

Comment: Actually, with Puma it's better to check additionally for Puma::Server: 

`Rails.const_defined?(:Server) || ($PROGRAM_NAME.include?('puma') && Puma.const_defined?(:Server))`

Comment: what about `rails test` ?

Answer (score 16):

Super helpful. Thanks @crishoj.

I wanted to examine the Console object more closely for another problem I am working on and found out that the Console constant can be reached with `Rails::Console`, so another option for checking would be to use:

```
defined? Rails::Console
defined? Rails::Server
```

Comment: `Rails::Server` is still defined in generator scripts like `rails g migration`. Also, `Rails::Console` is defined when running `rails s`.

Answer (score 12):

Using Rails 5 with or without an app-server like Puma/Passenger, here are three ways to determine how your app is running:

```
# We are running in a CLI console
defined?(Rails::Console)

# We are running as a Rack application (including Rails)
caller.any?{|l| l =~ %r{/config.ru/}}

# We are running as a CLI console
caller.any?{|l| l =~ %r{/lib/rake/task.rb:\d+:in `execute'}}
```

Comment: `caller.any?{|l| l =~ %r{/config.ru/}}` -- Shouldn't the trailing slash be removed? A fixed line is:`caller.any? {|l| l =~ %r"/config\.ru" }`

Comment: A slightly cleaner version: `caller.grep(%r{/config.ru}).any?`

Comment: The second line doesn't work in initializers.

Answer (score 3):

'Server' isn't defined when Rails 5 runs under Passenger.

The best solution I've found is a variant of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088025/detect-if-application-was-started-as-http-server-or-not-rake-task-rconsole-etc/12246652#answer-12242882) answer:

```
if %w(rails rake).include?(File.basename($0))
   <console or runner>
else
   <server>       
end
```

Comment: `Rails::Server` is still defined in generator scripts like `rails g migration`. Also, `Rails::Console` is defined when running `rails s`.

Answer (score 1):

In our project I had to detect console mode in **boot.rb**, for that I used:

```
in_console = (ARGV & ['c', 'console']).any?
```

Not a fool-proof solution, but good enough for our use case.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to `ARGV`. It was the only way to detect when `rails g` was called and not `rails s`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version that detects sidekiq or running server on passenger/puma. Given the previous answers, it is not 100% sure that it would work in all cases (I haven't tested what it's like when running a rails runner or a rake task in general)

```rb
@running_app = begin
  if defined?(Rails::Console)
    'Console'
  elsif Sidekiq.server?
    'Worker'
  elsif defined?(::PhusionPassenger) || defined?(Rails::Server) 
    'Server'
  else
    nil # unknown
  end
end
```

Answer (score -7):

For Padrino:

Console check:

```
if Padrino::constants.include? :Cli
    #your code
end
```

Server Check:

```
if !Padrino::constants.include? :Cli
    #your code
end
```