# Determine if using Rails console or server when using Spring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is it possible to determine if you are in the context of a running Rails server or console in an initializer when Spring is used? I've seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506690/how-to-determine-if-rails-is-running-from-cli-console-or-as-server) that don't take Spring into account.

Comment: how about `defined?(Rails)` ?

Comment: I want to know if I'm in the context of a running server OR a console. I need to be able to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Try `$PROGRAM_NAME.include? 'spring'`.